# Geo Location for Internal Networks

Tags: maxmind, private-network, geolite2

I am currently trying to add private network addresses to .mmdb file.
Is there any way to add private network related data into GeoLite2 MMDB file?

Answer (score -1):

If you refer to Private IP address range, then there is no way to geolocate it because the range can been used in any location in LAN.

Comment: Actually there was a way in previous versions by adding data to csv files and converting to dat . My problem is with new .mmdb files.

Comment: You mean you want to edit the MMDB file right? I refer to geolocation of private IP address range.

Comment: I want to edit MMDB file by adding private IP address ranges.